# For loop with if, else not working as it is printing the else if section even though element is in the array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I know that the loop is looping through every element in the array! Hence, it also prints out 'John is not found' before printing out his information! How do I just print out his information without 'John is not found'?

This is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Number of members: ");       
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    Member m[] = new Member[number];
    scanner.nextLine();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.print("Name & number:");
        String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ", 2);
        m[i] = new Member(input[0], input[1]);
    }  
    
    System.out.println("Information Saved.\n");
    
    boolean condition = true;
    while (condition) {
        System.out.print("Search a name or type exit: ");
        String search = scanner.nextLine();
            
        for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
            if (search.equals(m[x].getName())) {
                System.out.print(search + "'s number is " + m[x].getTel() + "\n");
                break;
            } else if (search.equals("exit")) {
                condition = false;
                m[x].showAllMembers();
            } else if (!search.equals(m[x].getName())){
                System.out.print(search + "is not found.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Member class:

```java
class Member {
    private String name, tel;
    
    public Member(String name, String tel ) { // Constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.tel = tel;
    }
    
    // Getter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
      
    // Setter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    // Getter
    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }
          
    // Setter
    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }
    
    public void showAllMembers() {
        System.out.print("Name:" + name + ", Number:" + tel + "\n");
    }
```

Results:
[image: After running it]

Comment: Hint: if you have an array of 100 items, how many times do you want to potentially print the "not found" part? And how many times is your "else" condition going to potentially execute? Additionally, do you really need to check for "exit" on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Should I not be using for loop but use Switch instead? I'm still not very sure..

Comment: I would personally refactor this: put the "search for a person" code into its own method and life would be much simpler. But no, a switch statement wouldn't help you here.

Comment: Ohhh yes! Thank you so much~~~ ^^

Comment: Im sorry do you mean putting the "search for a person" method into class Member?

Comment: No, I'd probably still have it in the same class as `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Number of members: ");       
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    Member m[] = new Member[number];
    scanner.nextLine();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.print("Name & number:");
        String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ", 2);
        m[i] = new Member(input[0], input[1]);
    }  
    
    System.out.println("Information Saved.\n");
    
    boolean condition = true;
    while (condition) {
        System.out.print("Search a name or type exit: ");
        String search = scanner.nextLine();
        
        if (search.equals("exit")) {
            condition = false;
            // method showAllMembers() should not exists in Member class, it'll be really better to migrate it to the separate method, because one single Member object shouldn't know anything about ALL members
            showAllMembers(m);
        }
        int memberNumber = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
            if (search.equals(m[x].getName())) {
                memberNumber = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (memberNumber != -1) {
            System.out.print(search + "'s number is " + m[memberNumber].getTel() + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print(search + "is not found.\n");
        }
    }
    
    public static void showAllMembers(Member members[]) {
        for (Member member : members) {
            System.out.println("Member name: " + member.getName() + ", number: " + member.getTel());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error here: memberNumber = m[x];

Comment: Sorry, just replace it by `memberNumber = x`;

Comment: ah thank you, but I still do not understand where to use showAllMembers() :')

Comment: it's better to create a separate method somewhere, but outside Member::class. It's even better to create in the Main class, let me show you how

Comment: @kwon pleas check out my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The code is printing the "not found" message too often at the moment because it's printing it *every time it finds a member which isn't a match*. You only want to print it when you've reached the end of the `for` loop.

Personally I'd extract the code into a method, which means you can just return when you've found the member. I'd also move the "check for exit" code outside the `for` loop.

So your `while` loop would look like this:

```java
// No need for a "condition" variable - just break when we've seen "exit"
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Search a name or type exit: ");
    String search = scanner.nextLine();
    if (search.equals("exit")) {
        break;
    }
    findMember(m, search);
}
```

And the `findMember` method would look like this:

```java
// TODO: You might want to return the member you've found
private static void findMember(Member[] members, String name) {
    for (Member member : members) {
        if (name.equals(member.getName()) {
            // TODO: use string formatting here
            System.out.println(name + "'s number is " + member.getTel());
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(name + " is not found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by taking the not found condition out of the for loop. Which will print the details if the name has been found, or print not found after the for loop finish to iterate and "found" variable is still false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Number of members: ");       
int number = scanner.nextInt();
Member m[] = new Member[number];
scanner.nextLine();

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    System.out.print("Name & number:");
    String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ", 2);
    m[i] = new Member(input[0], input[1]);
}  

System.out.println("Information Saved.\n");

boolean condition = true;
while (condition) {
    System.out.print("Search a name or type exit: ");
    String search = scanner.nextLine();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
        if (search.equals(m[x].getName())) {
            System.out.print(search + "'s number is " + m[x].getTel() + "\n");
            found = true;
            break;
        } else if (search.equals("exit")) {
            condition = false;
            m[x].showAllMembers();
    }
    if (!found) {
      System.out.print(search + "is not found.\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This won't compile, as 0 and 1 aren't valid values for `boolean`. Additionally, there's no explanation at all, which would make it a not-terribly-useful answer even if it worked.

Comment: it didnt work :'(, it still shows 'John is not found' even though I added

Comment: DId you add "found = true;" in the then statement?